# can't find previously imported js module

Tags: javascript, jquery, tag-it

I'm facing an error where a jQuery code can't find a previously imported module.

I'm using jQuery and tag-it (https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown)

I import the scripts in this order:

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-ui-touch-punch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/tag-it.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/tags.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

tag-it.min.js is the Tag-It provided js module and tags.js is my custom module.

tags.js is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var $available_tags = $('#user_tags').val().split(",").slice(0, -1);


$('#tags').tagit({
    fieldName: "tags",
    availableTags: $available_tags,
    placeholderText: "Enter Tags",
    beforeTagAdded: function(event, ui){
        var tag = ui.tag.text().slice(0, -1);
        if($.inArray( tag, $('#user_tags').val().split(",") ) == -1){
            $.get("/tags/add?tag=" + tag, function(data){
                if(!data.error){
                    $("#user_tags").val( $("#user_tags").val() + tag + ",");
                } else {
                    console.log("Eror", data);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    },
    showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
});


});
```

The error is in tags.js at line 6:

```
$('#tags').tagit({
```

Undefined error: tagit does not exist.
http://puu.sh/gCVUh/2d792035f6.png

How is this possible? The js loading order is fine and yet it seems not to recognice it.

Thanks in advance, if more information is needed ask for it and I'll update the thread.

Comment: Are you sure it loaded the js files? Check the console and see if there were any errors loading any of the sources. And also, did you load jQuery UI? That seems to also be a requirement.

Comment: Yes I loaded jquery and jquery UI. The error shows as follows: http://puu.sh/gCVUh/2d792035f6.png

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out why it wasn't working.

I just noticed that I duplicated jQuery script import some lines after these imports.

This was resseting jQuery enviroment and therefore, tag-it was removed from it.

Hope this helps someone in a future and thanks for the help!